# ASP MVC 5 Web Application not Rendering CSS. Deployed Via Web Deploy

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I deployed a MVC 5 Application via web deploy to IIS 8. It is not rendering my bootstrap.css. I'm not sure where to begin from a troubleshooting perspective as this is my first MVC 5 Deployment.

I attached my web config below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="JCI.MW.WebFrontEnd" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Bundle Config

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace JCI.MW.WebFrontEnd
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not rendering? Show your View HTML

Comment: Are there 404 errors for the bootstrap resources?

Comment: if you deployed your project before, and then now you modify a little bit your external bootstrap.css, maybe the browser store the file in the cache, try `ctrl` + `F5` in the browser to reload the resources from the server

Comment: @teovankot I am not seeing the bootstrap.css in the developer view.

Comment: See what I don't get is I have the bootstrap.css called in the appstart bundle config so it should be called. I added it to the original question.

Comment: @Jasen I am able to hit the CSS via the url.

Comment: I am getting this weird random string in lieu of my normal css

<link href="/MIE/Content/css?v=CIcesNvmOn0Nxijn5bm8cuJqiPS9FgU65o38LYn6AjM1" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: The weird string is the minified and packaged styles for production. You can try to disable this in your `RegisterBundles` function to help debug your problem `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;`.

Comment: Also, make sure you are not including any minified files in your bundles - that would cause some issues.